# to get response from external webservise that should only refresh part of the my joomla webpage

Tags: html, xml, web-services, joomla, http-post

I'm new to joomla. I used a link that display here as my web service: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius.
Then implemented a code to post some value to web service and got response, but it reload whole page of my hosted joomla site and display the empty form when i try to set the response value to form as answer because of the refreshing webpage. Then the values set as null. It didn't display the answer in the form, because I used condition to check if the form attributes are null it should display the empty form, but i could display the response value by using "echo $response;" before re-loading the form. I tried to use sessions, but it isn't solution for this. Can anyone help me get idea to fix that plz.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Fahrenheit'])&&$_POST['Fahrenheit']!=null) {
  $res = print_name($_POST['Fahrenheit']);
  print_form($res);
}
else {
  if($res == "")
  print_form($res);
}

// In this function we print the name the user provided.
function print_name($name) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $far = 'Fahrenheit='.$name;
  curl_setopt($ch,            CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$far);
  // receive server response ...
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);

 return $server_output;
}

// This function is called when no name was sent to us over HTTP.
function print_form($val) {
  echo '
    <form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Fahrenheit to Celsius:</td>
        <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="30" name="Fahrenheit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="cel" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td align="right">'.$val.'</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
    ';
}
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When reloading, Your page is invoking the service again. Add code snippet to the question to figure out where and what went wrong.

Comment: I uploaded my code.I haven't any idea to do that.I searched so many links.but It isn't working properly.plz give me a solution of code snippet that match with my joomla code.

Comment: I tested another code with ajax to refresh another php file and ane got response without form refreshing.But it gave me another problem.I can uploaded that file to server.but joomla doesn't support it.I didn't upload it in joomla back end.Because it should be uploaded as article.It also doesn't support php